# Refreshing JTable after changing data

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I want to refresh and display my `JTable` after a user pressed a button. Before that the button generates an `Object[][]` in which the filtered data from the table is held.
The filtered data is different only in the number of rows.

I'm using the netbeans UI creator and the only way I could populate the table with data is by defining the abstractTableModel. 
Here is the code of my abstractTableModel:

```
class myTable extends AbstractTableModel{
    private String[] stolpci = {"Kategorija","Podkategorija","Opis","Cena","Datum","Boni"};
    private Object[][] data = PregledovalnikGUI.vrniTabelo(); /*PregledovalnikGUI.vrniTabelo() returns a value in form of Object[][] in which the data is held*/
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return stolpci.length;
    }
    public int getRowCount() {
        return vrstice.length;
    }
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return stolpci[col];
    }
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return vrstice[row][col];
    }
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        vrstice[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
```

The jTable is set like:

```
Tabela.setModel(new myTable());
```

Which methods do I need to define to get the table to refresh at runtime?

Comment: all .... depends of whats refresh()

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside `myTable` you could have a method called `refresh()` something like this

```
public void refresh(Object[][] objects){
    //make the changes to the table, then call fireTableChanged
    fireTableChanged(null);
}
```

Then in the button listener, call the above method:

```
Tablea.refresh(objects);//objects stores your filtered data
```

Comment: Can I call refresh(objects) in ActionPerformed method for my button?

Comment: And can I do data = objects, where I replace "data" from the original table with the data from "objects"?

Comment: Can you show your code? I will have a better idea of what you are asking then

Comment: I solved my problem. The method that you suggested work. But there was a little bug on my end. The method which converted my List<> to Object[][] converted the wrong List<>. After replacing the wrong value the JTable refreshed correctly.

Comment: Where is fireTableChanged defined?

Comment: fireTableChanged is defined in the refresh method within AbstractTableModel.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a new `TableModel`, then nothing, the table will automatically update itself.

If the underlying data of the model is changed, then from within the model (seen as you extending from `AbstractTableModl`), you could call `fireTableDataChanged`, which lets the table know that the contents of the table have changed and it should redraw itself.

This may require that the model either have a refresh method of its own or that it has the capability to listen to changes from the data it is modelling